# Get current handler for ajaxStart event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a handler in a base file in app listening for ajaxStart:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        //do something
    });
```

But for specific requests, i want to replace this handler with another handler, make the request, then swap back in the old handler. So how can i get the handler(s) for the event "ajaxStart", then replace it? I tried to find an existing handler:

```
            var handlers = jQuery._data( document, "ajaxStart" );
            console.log('handlers are ');
            console.log(handlers);
```

But handlers was undefined....

Answer (score 0):

Without going into specifics as to what exactly you are trying to achieve with this, you can disable global handlers for individual ajax calls by passing in global: false as follows.

```
 $.ajax({
   global: false,
   beforeSend: function(){

   },
   complete: function(){
       }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different uses of Jquery._data in this page  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/. JQuery.data( element, key, value )
You have to use key in the method.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {  
    });
var handlers = jQuery._data( document,"test","ajaxStart" );
 console.log(handlers);
```

output:ajaxStart